# Load the same twitter bootstrap modal after the first one submitted

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal that have a form and it successfully submitted and get the success message, suppose I want to add a link to the same modal to load the same form from the current open modal.

When I click the link the modal hidden.

this is my link that links to the modal.

```
<a class="registerBtn" data-toggle="modal" href="#registerModalForm" >Register</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would approach this is to have the form data in a hidden div (let's call it `formData`) that is completely separate from the modal div. For example:

```
<div id="formData" class="hide">
   <form href="#" action="post">
      Name: <input id="nameText" type="text"/>
      <a href="#" id="mySubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
   </form>
</div>
```

Then create an event, so that when the modal shows, it loads the form data into the body of the modal:

```
$("#myModal").on("show", function() {
    // load the modal with content from the div formData
    $(".modal-body", this).html($("#formData").html());
});
```

Then finally, add an event to the button that reloads the form (here the button has an id = `myReload`:

```
$("body").on('click', 'a.btn-primary', function() {
      // A button with the class btn-primary was clicked. If this is the reload button
      // reload the HTML into the modal
      if ($(this).attr("id") == "myReload") {
                 $(this).parent().html($("#formData").html());
      }
});
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/WSepU/5/).  (Ignore the code for the submit button, this is just to simulate form submission).

Comment: Exactly the concept I want, I'm working to implement it on my case. but why in my case when I click submit the page reloads and the modal is hidden but the form is submitted.

Comment: You will have to submit the form using an ajax call if you don't want the page to reload, and populate the body of the modal in the success callback of the ajax call. Here is a good example: http://www.jstiles.com/Blog/How-To-Submit-a-Form-with-jQuery-and-AJAX

Comment: But I'm surprised why this happens when I insert the form via jQuery

Comment: Creating and adding the form using JQuery is separate from submitting the form.  You need to override the submit button behavior to submit using an ajax call.